# jquery append to unknown parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jScript that is creating dynamic html, and its being called like this:

```
<span id='thisNeedsToBeHere'><!-- notice arbitrary id name-->
    <script type='text/javascript'
                data-parm-one   = 'foo'
                data-parm-two   = 'bar'
                src='/dirOne/myJavascript.js'>
    </script>
</span>
```

This script needs the ability to be placed inside of any type of DOM element.

Inside of myJavascript.js we currently have the following:

```
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.innerHTML = 'blah blah blah';

  jQuery(      $(document.currentScript).parent()[0].tagName 
           +  '#'
           +   $(document.currentScript).parent()[0].id
        ).append(wrapper);
```

and this will append the wrapper to the parent element.

This works, but notice i have to assign an arbitrary id to the parent element, in this case i call it **thisNeedsToBeHere**.  Without an ID, it wont work.

```
<div id=''><!--this wont work because there is no div id defined-->
    <script type='text/javascript'
                data-parm-one   = 'foo'
                data-parm-two   = 'bar'
                src='/dirOne/myJavascript.js'>
    </script>
</div>
```

First thing I tried was using *$(this).append(wrapper)* but got this message back:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Is there a better way to append html to a parent element where we may not have an id?

Comment: You're using `Jquery` in your code, but you probably meant to write `jQuery`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you overcomplecated this. You don't need to construct CSS selector to select parent element as `parentNode.tagName + '#' + parentNode.id`, since you already have one available as `parent()`:

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = 'blah blah blah';

$(document.currentScript).parent().append(wrapper);
```

In fact, you don't even need wot worry selecting parent element to append to, with jQuery you can use `after` method:

```
$(document.currentScript).after(wrapper);
```

Comment: both of your solutions worked perfectly - thank you very much.  i decided to go with your suggestion of "after" instead of "append".